# How can I sort Map values by key in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a Map that has strings for both keys and values.

The data is like the following:

> "question1", "1"
> "question9", "1"
> "question2", "4"
> "question5", "2"

I want to sort the map based on its keys. So, in the end, I will have `question1, question2, question3`, and so on.

Eventually, I am trying to get two strings out of this Map:

- First String: Questions (in order 1 .. 10)
- Second String: Answers (in the same order as the question)

Right now I have the following:

```
Iterator it = paramMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    questionAnswers += pairs.getKey() + ",";
}
```

This gets me the questions in a string, but they are not in order.

Comment: Provided you cannot use TreeMap, in Java 8 we can make use of toMap() method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40649809/1216775

Answer (score 728):

### Short answer

Use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).  This is precisely what it's for.

If this map is passed to you and you cannot determine the type, then you can do the following:

```
SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());
for (String key : keys) { 
   String value = map.get(key);
   // do something
}
```

This will iterate across the map in natural order of the keys.

---

### Longer answer

Technically, you can use anything that implements `SortedMap`, but except for rare cases this amounts to `TreeMap`, just as using a `Map` implementation typically amounts to `HashMap`.

For cases where your keys are a complex type that doesn't implement Comparable or you don't want to use the natural order then `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` have additional constructors that let you pass in a `Comparator`:

```
// placed inline for the demonstration, but doesn't have to be a lambda expression
Comparator<Foo> comparator = (Foo o1, Foo o2) -> {
        ...
    }

SortedSet<Foo> keys = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
keys.addAll(map.keySet());
```

Remember when using a `TreeMap` or `TreeSet` that it will have different performance characteristics than `HashMap` or `HashSet`.  Roughly speaking operations that find or insert an element will go from **O(1)** to **O(Log(N))**.

In a `HashMap`, moving from 1000 items to 10,000 doesn't really affect your time to lookup an element, but for a `TreeMap` the lookup time will be about 1.3 times slower (assuming Log<sub>2</sub>).  Moving from 1000 to 100,000 will be about 1.6 times slower for every element lookup.

Comment: I'm trying to use Treemap and sort String keys based on length. I find I'm getting inconsistent retrieval results. Apparently because TreeMap considers a compareTo result of 0 as "equals"? Not sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: compareTo() result of 0 is 'equals'.  If you're writing a comparator that sorts by string length, then you need to return a positive or negative value based on which string is longer, and only return 0 if both strings are the same length.  if a and b are strings you can do this like so `return a.length() - b.length()' (or reverse the values if you want them sorted in the other direction).

Comment: Hello guys, if he/she would to the Map to be orderd by keys, which here is 1,2,3,4 , what is the insertation order.... why not we using LinkedHashSet ? We just put the questions one by one, and it is getting ordered by the order of the insertation. Can some help me out with this ?

Comment: @Karoly LinkedHashSet would work to retrieve the elements in the order you inserted them.  What the OP is wanting is to retrieve the elements in some predetermined sort order, irrespective of insertion order.

Comment: @cricket_007 the code is demonstrating specifically how to iterate across they keys for a map that isn't already sorted.

Comment: log₂(1000)≈10, log₂(10000)≈13 (rounding). That's 1.3 times slower, not 3 times!

Answer (score 161):

Assuming TreeMap is not good for you (and assuming you can't use generics):

```
List sortedKeys=new ArrayList(yourMap.keySet());
Collections.sort(sortedKeys);
// Do what you need with sortedKeys.
```

Comment: Thanks!  I needed to do something like this since my keys were a complex type.

Comment: This will just sort the keys list, but won't sort the map itself based on the keys. I am also looking how to sort the map based on the keys and could find a way. I will have to try with TreeMap I guess:)

Comment: sortedKeys.sort() will do fine if you use java 8+

Comment: aliciaKeys.sing();

Comment: I don't know why is this upvoted, this answer will only sort the keys not the Map. Even if you try to create a new HashMap and insert elements by sorted keys, your new HashMap will NOT preserve the insertion order.

Comment: @YassirKhaldi hasmap is not that thing to keep elements in order, you may generate output then sorting but hasmap stay as it is

Comment: you then get the values from the map using the sorted keys of the list

Answer (score 79):

Using the `TreeMap` you can sort the map.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();        
Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(map);
for (String str : treeMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Map<String, List<String>> treeMap = new TreeMap<String,     List<String>>(printHashMap);
  for (String str : treeMap.keySet()) {
      
      System.out.println(str +  "         " + treeMap.get(str));
  }

Answer (score 57):

Just use TreeMap:

```
new TreeMap<String, String>(unsortMap);
```

Be aware that the TreeMap is sorted according to the natural ordering of its 'keys'.

Answer (score 42):

Use a [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)!

Comment: I don't know Java :-( This works 100%. A lot simpler than any of the horrible solutions I came up with

Answer (score 42):

If you already have a map and would like to sort it on keys, simply use:

```
Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(yourMap);
```

A complete working example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

class SortOnKey {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
       hm.put("3", "three");
       hm.put("1", "one");
       hm.put("4", "four");
       hm.put("2", "two");
       printMap(hm);
       Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(hm);
       printMap(treeMap);
    } // main

    public static void printMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        Set s = map.entrySet();
        Iterator it = s.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
           Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
           String key = (String) entry.getKey();
           String value = (String) entry.getValue();
           System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
        } // while
        System.out.println("========================");
    } // printMap

} // class
```

Answer (score 33):

Provided you cannot use `TreeMap`, in **Java 8** we can make use of the [toMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) method in `Collectors` which takes the following parameters:

- **keymapper**: mapping function to produce keys
- **valuemapper**: mapping function to produce values
- **mergeFunction**: a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key
- **mapSupplier**: a function which returns a new, empty Map into which the
  results will be inserted.

**Java 8 Example**

```
Map<String, String> sample = new HashMap<>(); // Push some values to map
Map<String, String> newMapSortedByKey = sample.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByKey().reversed())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
Map<String, String> newMapSortedByValue = sample.entrySet().stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByValue().reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

We can modify the example to use custom comparator and to sort based on keys as:

```
Map<String, String> newMapSortedByKey = sample.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 23):

Using **Java 8:**

```
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 20):

### In Java 8

To sort a `Map<K, V>` by key, putting keys into a `List<K>`:

```
List<K> result = map.keySet().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To sort a `Map<K, V>` by key, putting entries into a `List<Map.Entry<K, V>>`:

```
List<Map.Entry<K, V>> result =
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Last but not least: to sort **strings** in a locale-sensitive manner - use a [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) (comparator) class:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY); // case insensitive collator

List<Map.Entry<String, String>> result =
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(collator))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

This code can sort a key-value map in both orders, i.e., ascending and descending.

```
<K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByValues
     (final Map<K, V> map, int ascending)
{
     Comparator<K> valueComparator =  new Comparator<K>() {
        private int ascending;
        public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
            int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
            if (compare == 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return ascending*compare;
        }
        public Comparator<K> setParam(int ascending)
        {
              this.ascending = ascending;
              return this;
        }
    }.setParam(ascending);

    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
}
```

As an example:

```
Map<Integer, Double> recommWarrVals = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
recommWarrVals = sortByValues(recommWarrVals, 1);  // Ascending order
recommWarrVals = sortByValues(recommWarrVals, -1);  // Descending order
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String str : map.keySet()) {
  list.add(str);
}

Collections.sort(list);

for (String str : list) {
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you don't want to use a `TreeMap`:

```java
public static Map<Integer, Integer> sortByKey(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey));
    Map<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    list.forEach(e -> sortedMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Also, in case you wanted to sort your map on the basis of `values`, just change `Map.Entry::getKey` to `Map.Entry::getValue`.

Comment: This came up in my review log.  Someone tried to fix some errors with variables names (but failed).  So, I fixed them correctly, however, this answer is just wrong fundamentally.  The order in which you add values to a HashMap is irrelevant.  Maps do not have order.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710193/how-to-preserve-insertion-order-in-hashmap

Comment: What is `e` variable at your source code? `(e.getKey(), e.getValue())`

Comment: @aepryus The answer is not wrong. The order of insertion order in LinkedHashMap is relevant. That's the main point of having the LinkedHashMap. The order of insertion is irrelevant for the HashMaps.

Comment: @SergeySargsyan It appears the answerer changed to a LInkedHashMap 6 months after my comment.  I'm unfamiliar with LinkedHashMap, but I'll take you word for it that my comment is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

### Using `TreeMap`

Let's initialize a map with some random key-value pairs

```java
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("key5", "value5",
            "key2", "value2",
            "key4", "value4",
            "key1", "value1",
            "key3", "value3");
```

##### Sort by map's key in ascending order

```java
Map<String, String> sortedTreeMap = new TreeMap<>(map);

System.out.println(sortedTreeMap);
// {key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3, key4=value4, key5=value5}
```

##### Sort by map's key in descending order

```java
Map<String, String> reverseSortedTreeMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
reverseSortedTreeMap.putAll(map);

System.out.print(reverseSortedTreeMap);
// {key5=value5, key4=value4, key3=value3, key2=value2, key1=value1}
```

Source: [Sort Map by Key using TreeMap in Java](https://codingnconcepts.com/java/sort-map-by-key-using-treemap/)

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can also use .stream().sorted():

```
myMap.keySet().stream().sorted().forEach(key -> {
        String value = myMap.get(key);

        System.out.println("key: " + key);
        System.out.println("value: " + value);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is provided [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-hashmap-according-key-value-java/).  We have a `HashMap` that stores values in unspecified order.  We define an auxiliary `TreeMap` and we copy all data from HashMap into TreeMap using the `putAll` method.  The resulting entries in the TreeMap are in the key-order.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinkedHashMap`, which provides the key ordering. It's also gives the same performance as `HashMap`. They both implement the `Map` interface, so you can just replace the initialization object `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` was enough for me, since I already have a sorted collection of keys and I am inserting them in order too, no need of implementing any Comparable/Comparator interface

Comment: Re *"the same performance with HashMap"*: Do you mean *"the same performance* ***as*** *HashMap"*

Answer (score 1):

Use the below tree map:

```
Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
    .thenComparing(Function.identity()));
```

Whatever you put in this sortedMap, it will be sorted automatically. First of all, `TreeMap` is sorted implementation of `Map` Interface.

There is a *but* as it sorts keys in the [natural order fashion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). As the Java documentation says, `String` type is a *lexicographic natural* order type. Imagine the below list of numbers with the String type. It means the below list will *not* be sorted as expected.

`List<String> notSortedList = List.of("78","0", "24", "39", "4","53","32");`

If you just use the default `TreeMap` constructor like below and push each element one-by-one like below:

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (String s : notSortedList) {
    map.put(s, s);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

The output is: `{0=0, 14=14, 24=24, 32=32, 39=39, 4=4, 48=48, 53=53, 54=54, 78=78}`

As you see, number *4*, for example, comes after '39'. This is the nature of the lexicographic data types, like String. If that one was an *Integer* data type then that was okay though.

To fix this, use an argument to first check the length of the String and then compare them. In [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) it is done like this:

```
Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
    .thenComparing(Function.identity()));
```

It first compares each element by length then apply check by `compareTo` as the input the same as the element to compare with.

If you prefer to use a more understandable method, the above code will be equivalent with the below code:

Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(
new Comparator() {
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
int lengthDifference = o1.length() - o2.length();
if (lengthDifference != 0)
return lengthDifference;
return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
}
);

Because the `TreeMap` constructor accepts the comparator Interface, you can build up any an even more complex implementation of Composite classes.

This is also another form for a simpler version.

```
Map<String,String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(
   (Comparator<String>) (o1, o2) ->
    {
        int lengthDifference = o1.length() - o2.length();
        if (lengthDifference != 0)
            return lengthDifference;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

We can also sort the key by using Arrays.sort method.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Object[] objArr = new Object[map.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
    objArr[i] = map.get(i);
}

Arrays.sort(objArr);

for (Object str : objArr) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: This is sorting by value and not key.