# My application crashes when 2:nd dialog window is answered

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I got a weird problem with my method that's creating dialoges with questions. Basically what I've done is creating a hashmap table with questions and a identifier, which I'm using for my if-statements on the positive -and negative buttons of the dialog window.

Here's the program code:

```
public class QuestionsActivity extends Activity {
String question = null;
String identifier = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);


    // 0 = call showRiskEvaluationDialog() on button NO.  1 = call showRiskEvaluationDialog(); on button YES
    Map<String, String> question_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    question_map.put("Have you cut the power?", "0");
    question_map.put("Have you not cut the power?", "1");
    question_map.put("Do you know your work assignment?", "0");
    question_map.put("Don't you know your work assignment?", "1");

    //For loop to extract a question and identifier from the hashmap
    for(Entry<String, String> entry : question_map.entrySet()) 
    {
        question = entry.getKey();
        identifier = entry.getValue();

        create_dialog_method(question);
    }

}

/**
 * Method to create a dialogbox with a question and YES, NO buttons
 * @param question_param
 */
public void create_dialog_method(String question_param) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Titel");
    alert.setMessage(question_param);

    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            if (identifier.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                showRiskEvaluationDialog();

                identifier = null;
            } else if (identifier.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                identifier = null;

            }

        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            if (identifier.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                showRiskEvaluationDialog();

                identifier = null;

            } else if (identifier.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                identifier = null;
            }

        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

PROBLEM: First of all it seems to loop through the hashmap in a weird order. It's starting with **"Have you not cut the power?"** and therefor skipping the first question. **The main problem** when I run the program is that the application crash after I've answered the 2:nd dialog popup. Basically it runs through 1 question perfectly but when I'm answering the 2:nd question it krasches, no matter what button I reply with.

Here's the errors:

```
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at   com.example.ovakoappen.QuestionsActivity$2.onClick(QuestionsActivity.java:85)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:185)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-26 14:13:35.163: E/AndroidRuntime(7953):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the ordering problem: you could use [LinkedHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to ensure the ordering.
2. The `NullPointerException` is the result of calling method `equalsIgnoreCase` on null object, you set `identifier` to `null` in the first iteration: you should make `question` and `identifier` method parameters rather than fields.

here is the code after change:

```
    public class QuestionsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

       // false = call showRiskEvaluationDialog() on button NO
       // true  = call showRiskEvaluationDialog() on button YES
       Map<String, Boolean> question_map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>();
       question_map.put("Have you cut the power?", false);
       question_map.put("Have you not cut the power?", true);
       question_map.put("Do you know your work assignment?", false);
       question_map.put("Don't you know your work assignment?", true);

       // For loop to extract a question and identifier from the Map
       for (Entry<String, Boolean> entry : question_map.entrySet()){
          create_dialog_method(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
       }
    }

    /**
     * Method to create a dialogbox with a question and YES, NO buttons
     *
     * @param question_param
     * @param identifier
     */
    public void create_dialog_method(String question_param, final boolean identifier) {
       AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

       alert.setTitle("Title");
       alert.setMessage(question_param);

       alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

             if (identifier)
                showRiskEvaluationDialog();
             else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
       });

       alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

             if (identifier)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             else
                showRiskEvaluationDialog();
          }
       });
       alert.show();
    }

    private void showRiskEvaluationDialog() {}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem! I just had to make a small adjustment by swapping place with the method call and Toast under the NO button.

Comment: @user Sorry I didn't notice that, I've fixed the answer to reflect the proper logic

Answer (score 0):

About the first "problem" with the order: A hash map does not guarantee a specific order. More presicely the order doesn't even have to be constant over the time. You would have to use something else instead.

Comment: Ah okay thx! I was using an arraylist before but I wanted to be able to put the "identifier" and then seperate it from the question. Hence why i choosed hash map. But I think I would want the questions to be shown in a specific order.

Comment: well, looking at the Java API (which is somehow very related to the Android Java API), I would take a look at classes which implement the SortedMap interface. This should solve your problem: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Answer (score 0):

For your order problem, you can see use a `LinkedHashMap` which will get you items in the insertion order ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710193/how-to-preserve-inserting-order-in-hashmap))

For the crash you encounter, it is because all dialogs are created at once in the `onCreate` method of your activity and once you validate a dialog, your variable `identifier` becomes null. You should only create one dialog at a time and create the following in the dismissListener of your dialog. Details about dismiss listeners [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29).

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in the code:

you create N dialogs (here, at least 4) in a loop. Yet each of the dialogs utilizes the same `question`/`identifier` variables.

Meaning: the 1st one will change `identifier` value after it exits, and this value will use 2nd dialog. Dialogs in Android are non-blocking. When you show a dialog, the execution of `create_dialog_method()` ends and the for-loop is running! Even if you have dialog still visible, another one will be created on top of it.

In effect you have 4 dialogs created one by one, all shown but one visible.

Then in an `onClick()` method you set `identifier` to null. This is the value that the 2nd dialog will see and this is why it crashes.

There are at least 2 solutions:

1. Create only one dialog at a time, and create new one after you close it with yes/no  button or on a dismiss listener.
2. Create your own dialog class and pass question/identifier there -- so they are independent from your main question map.

Comment: Ah okay, thx for the explanation! That's how i want my solution to be(creating one dialog at a time).I'm still unsure how to get there code-wise though.