# What data structure should I use for a high score list?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)
>   [how to sort Map values by key in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java)

I am trying to keep track of scores and I need to be able to sort the scores into non-ascending order without getting the keys and values out of line. My first thought was to use a map but I'm really struggling to find a way to keep a map sorted by value. The values are all Integer objects. How would I go about sorting a high score list like this?

Comment: This post seems to describe your issue:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Answer (score 1):

This is a Microsoft / Amazon job interview type of question.
You can use a priority queue, in other to have the highest score as the first element of the queue. Create a node as `key | value` pair. Implement it in a way the key order is maintained by the score value, and implement the queue.

---

Giving more details

---

This is your `Node` implementation:

```
public class Node{

    private String name;        // the name
    private double score;       // assuming you're using double

    public Node(String name, double score){
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;         // assuming negative scores are allowed
    }
    public void updateScore(double score){
        this.score += score;
    }
}
```

And when you use `PriorityQueue`, make the `Comparison` based on the score value. If you need to search / update, it is O(1), according to the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> Implementation note: this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for
>   the enqueing and dequeing methods (offer, poll, remove() and add);
>   linear time for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods; and
>   constant time for the retrieval methods (peek, element, and size).

Read the API, I guess you probably need to overwrite the `Comparator<? super E> comparator()`, or at least modify it for your needs. That should do it.

Comment: This is a question about sorting maps. How is a PriorityQueue relevant?

Comment: @Bohemian No, it's not. It's a question about which data structure is best for the job. OP simply explained that he _tried_ with a map, not that he _wants_ a map-based solution.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how I would use a PriorityQueue in order to sort the Integer values while still maintaining the position of the Strings.

Comment: Could you write me a small code snippet please?

Comment: @SaxSalute I gave more details about the implementation. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @SaxSalute I may give you some code snippet, but I need to know which programming language you're using.

Comment: @SaxSalute I updated my question. I guess you have now all the base you need to get your job done.