# Access values of hashmap

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

I am having a MAP, `Map<String, Records> map = new HashMap<String, Records> ();`

```
public class Records 
{
    String countryName;
    long numberOfDays;

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }
    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }
    public long getNumberOfDays() {
        return numberOfDays;
    }
    public void setNumberOfDays(long numberOfDays) {
        this.numberOfDays = numberOfDays;
    }

    public Records(long days,String cName)
    {
        numberOfDays=days;
        countryName=cName;
    }

    public Records()
    {
        this.countryName=countryName;
        this.numberOfDays=numberOfDays;
    }
```

I have implemented the methods for map, now please tell me How do I access all the values that are present in the hashmap. I need to show them on UI in android ?

Comment: What error you come across? You should able to get the record by the key you assigned for the record or you can iterate it by foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Map#entrySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) method, if you want to access the `keys` and `values` parallely from your `HashMap`: -

```
Map<String, Records> map = new HashMap<String, Records> ();

//Populate HashMap

for(Map.Entry<String, Record> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Also, you can override `toString` method in your `Record` class, to get String Representation of your `instances` when you print them in `for-each` loop.

**UPDATE**: -

If you want to sort your `Map` on the basis of `key` in alphabetical order, you can convert your `Map` to `TreeMap`. It will automatically put entries sorted by keys: -

```
    Map<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(map);

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: treeMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());

    }
```

For more detailed explanation, see this post: - [how to sort Map values by key in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java)

Comment: Is there any way by which I can sort keys are per alphabetical order ?

Comment: @onkar. You can use `TreeMap` for that case. See this post: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java

Answer (score 6):

You can do it  by using for loop

```
Set keys = map.keySet();   // It will return you all the keys in Map in the form of the Set


for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) 
{

      String key = (String) i.next();

      Records value = (Records) map.get(key); // Here is an Individual Record in your HashMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map.values()` gives you a `Collection` with all the values in your `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having `HashMap` ready with data, then you just need to iterate over `HashMap` keys. Just implement an iteration and fetch data one by one.

Check this: [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap)