# Sorting on the basis of Keys

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have a collection in the form of key, value pair and I was trying to sort it on the basis of
key itself
 the values in the collection  is

```
cd,20
ef,65
ab,28
gh,76
```

Now as shown the first is key , please advise me the ways by which I can sort it on the basis of key itself,
That is the output that I was looking would be.

```
ab,28
cd,20
ef,65
gh,76
```

Comment: use a `TreeMap<String, Integer>`, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Just create a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) from the original Map. A TreeMap is sorted according to the natural ordering of the keys, and consequently

```
for (Map.Entry e : treeMap.entrySet()) {
   // generics elided for clarity
```

will be sorted. From the doc for `entrySet()`:

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set's
>   iterator returns the entries in ascending key order.

Using `entrySet()` means you can pull the keys and corresponding values in one operation, rather than have to get the keys, and go back to the map for the value. It's a small optimisation, but worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
// insert entries:
map.put("ab", 12);
// ...
// insertion order does not matter
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ", " + map.get(key));
}
// will always print in sorted order
```