# How to sort three arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have three arrays in my proggramme Surname, Forename and result and need to create a sort array
Surname: Chris Forename: Charleton: Result: 54
Surname: Annett: forename: Lyle: result 67
If I wanted to sort it by alphabetical of last name, i need all the fields to move, instead of just the surname. This is the bubble sort code i'm working off

```
    int swap;
    boolean swapflag = true;
    //outer loop
    while (swapflag == true)
    {
        swapflag = false;
        //inner loop
        for (int index=0; index < (nums.length - 1); index++)
        {
            //swap routine
            if (nums[index]> nums[index + 1])
            {   //swap routine
                swap = nums[index];
                nums[index] = nums[index + 1];
                nums[index + 1] = swap;
                swapflag = true;
            }
        }//end inner
    }//end outer

    System.out.println ("\nArray Contents after sorting"
            + "\n*************");

    for (int index=0; index < nums.length; index ++)
    {  
        System.out.println("Array element " 
                + index + ": " + nums[index]);  
    }
}
```

}

```
   `     package projStudent;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UnitResults 
{
    //delcare Scanner as keyb
    static Scanner keyb = new Scanner (System.in);
    //declare fields
    static String studentForename [];
    static String studentSurname [];
    static int [] studentResult;

    static int pointer;

    //constructor
    UnitResults(int sizeofclass)
    {//start of constructor
        studentForename = new String [sizeofclass];
        studentSurname = new String [sizeofclass];
        studentResult = new int [sizeofclass];
        pointer = 0;
    }//end of constructor

    public boolean add(String studentForename[], String studentSurname[],
             int studentResult[])
    {//start of add method
        if (pointer == studentResult.length )
        {//start of if statement
            System.out.println("Sorry Array is full");
            return false;
            studentResult[pointer] = studentResult[];
            pointer ++;
        }//end of if statement


    }//end of add method
    public boolean delete(int element)
    {//start of delete method
        element = element - 1;
        if ((element >= 0) && ( element < pointer))
        {//start of if statement
            for(int index = (element + 1); index < pointer; index++)
            {//start of for statement
                studentResult[index - 1] = studentResult[index];   
            }//end of for statement
            pointer--;
            return true;
        }//end of if statement
        else
        {//start of else statement
            return false;
        }//end of else statement  
    }//end of delete method

       public String find()
    {//start of display
        String strOutput="";
        strOutput = strOutput + "Students";
        if (pointer==0)
        {//start of if statement
            strOutput = strOutput + "There are no records in this Array";
            return strOutput;
        }//end of if statement

    for (int index=0; index < pointer; index++)
    {//start of for method
        strOutput = strOutput + "Student Name" + studentSurname[index] + studentForename + 
                "Student Result" + studentResult +"\n";
    }//end of for method

    return strOutput;
}//display
   public int sort (int UnitResults)

   {//start of sort
       int sort;
       boolean swapflag = true;
       while (swapflag == true)
       {//start of while loop
           swapflag = false;
           for (int index=0; index < (UnitResults - 1); index++)
           {
               if (studentResult[index]> studentResult[index + 1])
            {   //swap routine
                sort = studentResult[index];
                studentResult[index] = studentResult[index + 1];
                studentResult[index + 1] = sort;

                swapflag = true;
            }


           }

       }//end of while loop

   }//end of sort
```

}`

Comment: **Java** and **JavaScript** are two completely different languages.

Comment: Why are you using 3 arrays, instead of one? Can't you combine the three values belonging to a person into a Person class or something, and put that in an array?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your post is confusing as you don't include some things, like just what is the current array you are sorting.  Still, if I understand your question correctly...

Regardless of the language, your strategy would involve changes to how you swap the elements.  If your array consists of composite data, then simply assigning in a swap is fine.  If your data is scattered, then your swap needs to swap each variable.  You can always just sort the indices of the array into another array, then use that array to indirectly reference the first, for sorted access.

Comment: I was going to suggest an array of indices as well.  Keep your other three arrays in the same order, and sort the index array however you need to.

Comment: This is my current code, i'm just trying it with one of my arrays studentResult. I added the code to my comment

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an List for this purpose.
First create an object. For example "Person" containing members for "Forname","Surename","Result". Then fill the list with these objects, implement the Interface Compareable and use the Collection.sort() methode.

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
   private String forname;
   private String surname;
   private int rating;

   public Person(String forename, String surname, int rating)
   {
         this.forname = forename;
         this.surname = surname;
         this.rating = rating 
   }

  public int compareTo(Person p) {
       if(p.rating == this.rating) 
          return 0;
       else if(p.rating < this.rating) 
            return -1;

       return 1;  
  }


}

class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

         Person p1 = new Person("John","Smith",10);
         Person p2 = new Person("Max","Muster",20);
         Person p3 = new Person("Sarah","Clark",15);

         personList.add(p1);
         personList.add(p2);
         personList.add(p3);

         personList.sort();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of features of the Java programming languages that can help you resolve the problem that you are having, the first of which is inclusion of appropriate data structures and methods with which to manipulate objects within those data structures.

First and foremost, I'd recommend using a java class to represent a single person entity... think about it, when you look up a person's information, you don't consult three separate books, or computer screens, or what have you, when all that information can be organized into one place.  For your person above, for example, you could use something like this:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int result;

    public Person(String fn, String ln, int r) {
        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
        result = r;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person otherPerson) {
       return lastName.compareTo(otherPerson.lastName);
    }

}
```

This will give you an object that will store all of your person information, and by default will be easily sortable by last name (you can change this behavior with a comparator, which I won't cover here.)

Now instead of having three different arrays of first names, last names, and results, you can have a single array of Persons.  There ARE actually sorting mechanisms within the java language for arrays already, which you can research and use if you choose, but if you'd like to use your own sort, you would just need to replace your swap conditional with something like this:

```
if(persons[index].compareTo(persons[index+1]) > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just want ask you

why instead creating class student ie

> ```
> class Student{
>      private String studentForename;
>      private String studentSurname;
>      private int studentResult;
> //setters and getters
> }
> ```

and put them in some collection ie List
you are putting them into 3 different arrays?

do you realize, if you have them nicely in the list, you can sort them just by using `Collections.sort()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand properly the question: are you looking for a way to manually implement a sorting algorithm (bubble, quick or whatever) or you would like to simply sort them the best you can? Generally speaking you should never implement your own sort 'cause Java provides itself a very efficient lot... or is this an exercise? Probably :)

Best way I can imagine is, provided the 3 arrays in their original form are linked by index, create a surname/index map, load it form surname array, sort the Map.Entry by key and then you will have the array indexes sorted the way you wanted. Check here for more details: [how to sort Map values by key in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java)

PS The solutions provided by the others are correct and preferrable if you are NOT doing an exercise :) Better deal with a structured object than with 3 separated data.