# store data in table by ascending IDs

Tags: java, mysql, treemap, linkedhashmap

i have a program where i have to read data from excel file and store them in a database . I am using LinkedHashmap to read each cell as a string and store them. My excel file contains the data:

```
ID    Name        Salary
43    paulina     1000
5     christine   2349000
54    laura       12587458
49    jim         45878
```

In my code I have made the fields for the table by the first row of the excel file and then I have filled the table with the rest of the data using again LinkedHashMap.
My question is how in this step I can store the data in the table not the way they are in the file but by ascending IDs. I search that i can do it with TreeMap but how exactly?
Could anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean " which database"?

Comment: This is what i mean by which database " i have to read data from excel file and store them in a database". See the last word. Is it oracle, sybase, access?

Comment: In a database that i have select in the beginning of my program when i make the connection!

Comment: try using a TreeMap instead or create a TreeMap from your HashMap.

Comment: Could you help me how i will  create a TreeMap from my LinkedHashMap?

Comment: The answer to the question in this link should point you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to sort for the database, then loki is right: it is unimportant.  If your question is how to order it for the program... You can use TreeMap, it's a fast data structure.  You need to either make the objects that go in the structure implement Comparable, or you need to construct your TreeMap with a Comparator.  Read up on the official Java tutorial on the two - either is ok to use, it's just a slightly different style of programming.

Answer (score 0):

A characteristic of DBMSs (like MySQL, Oracle, etc) is that each row of data stands alone.  There is no natural order in which rows are stored in a DBMS.

That is, when you retrieve the rows using a `SELECT` statement, the order in which they will be presented to you in your result set is formally unpredictable.  If you want your rows presented in a predictable order, use an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` statement.

It happens that some DBMS technology presents the illusion that rows are stored in a particular order.  But they make no promises about this, and the illusion can break at any time unless you use `ORDER BY`.  I learned this the hard way when an application started malfunctioning when a table got to a certain size.

To order your rows before `INSERT`ing them into MySQL is, therefore, a waste of your time.  Keep your insertion software really simple.  To order them when you get them out is trivially easy -- use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: You are right and i know that i can do what i am trying to do with the commands in mysql! But my project is to do it programatically! That's why i am asking!