# Get smallest available key (>= 1) in a HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary

I am using a Map in which I save all tracks that the user registers. Every new track should be assigned a new ID which starts at 1. However, if tracks 1, 2, 3, 4 exist and the user deletes track with ID 1 the next added track gets the smallest available ID >=1 which in this case would be 1.

How is it possible to do this efficiently? Or is there a better datatype available?

```
private Map<Integer, Track> tracks;

public Register() {
    this.trains = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addTrack(Track track) {
    int id = <get Smallest Value Available >= 1>;
    this.tracks.put(id, track);
}

public void removeTrack(int id) {
    if (tracks.containsKey(id)) {
        this.tracks.remove(id);
    } else {
        Terminal.printError("track with ID " + id + " doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution looks for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345131/fastest-way-to-determine-the-lowest-available-key-in-java-hashmap

Comment: I don't need the smallest saved value. I want to prevent gaps when deleting a track. E. g. tracks 1, 2, 3 exist. The user deletes track 2. Then he adds another track that gets ID 2

Comment: You will get unpopular fast if you first post, then within 7 minutes answer and then shortly after delete (for another Q/A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:** You can use `TreeMap` and iterate through its keys, and if there is a gap between two keys, you can insert your element in this gap. Addition will work in `O(currentKeysCount)` worst-case, deletion will work in `O(log(currentKeysCount))`.

```java
private TreeMap<Integer, Track> tracks;

public Register() {
    this.trains = new TreeMap<>();
}

public void addTrack(Track track) {
    int id = 1;
    for (int key : this.trains.keySet) {
        if (key > id) break;
        id = key + 1;
    }
    this.tracks.put(id, track);
}

public void removeTrack(int id) {
    if (tracks.containsKey(id)) {
        this.tracks.remove(id);
    } else {
        Terminal.printError("track with ID " + track.getId() + " doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:** You can create a `PriorityQueue` that will store deleted keys. Addition and deletion will work in `O(log(currentKeysCount) + log(deletedKeysCount))`.

```java
private Map<Integer, Track> tracks;
private PriorityQueue<Integer> deletedKeys;
private int nextKey;

public Register() {
    this.trains = new HashMap<>();
    this.deletedKeys = new PriorityQueue<>();
    this.nextKey = 0;
}

public void addTrack(Track track) {
    int id = nextKey;
    if (!deletedKeys.isEmpty()) id = deletedKeys.poll();
    this.tracks.put(id, track);
}

public void removeTrack(int id) {
    if (tracks.containsKey(id)) {
        this.tracks.remove(id);
        this.deletedKeys.add(id);
    } else {
        Terminal.printError("track with ID " + track.getId() + " doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

**Approach 3:** It may be much easier to ignore missing keys and just increase `nextKey` counter on every addition (you can even use `long` instead of `int`). Unless you add a new key more often than once per millisecond, your program won't fail earlier than all code that uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` (and it will fail in more than 292 million years). Addition and deletion will work in `O(log(currentKeysCount))`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a loop and see if the which value is not yet included in the map

```
public Integer getId(Map<Integer, Track> tracks) {
    // Set on max-value
    Integer id = Collections.max(tracks.keySet()) + 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= tracks.keySet().size(); i++) {
        if (!tracks.keySet().contains(i)) {
            // lower value available
            id = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return id;
}
```

Comment: I don't need the smallest saved value. I want to prevent gaps when deleting a track. E. g. tracks 1, 2, 3 exist. The user deletes track 2. Then he adds another track that gets ID 2

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake Yes, i know. First you remove the track from the map and then you call the "getId" method, which determines the current lowest Id.

Answer (score 0):

Say if from 100 trains number 40 and number 60 are free, you want to get 40 from {40, 60}.

```
private final Map<Integer, Track> tracks = new HashMap<>();;
private final SortedSet<Integer> freeIds = new TreeSet<>();

public synchronized void addTrack(Track track) {
    int id;
    if (freeIds.isEmpty()) {
        id = 1 + tracks.size(); // Numbering from 1
    } else {
        id = freeIds.first();
        freeIds.remove(id);
    }
    track.setId(id);
    tracks.put(id, track);
}

public synchronized void removeTrack(int id) {
    Track track = tracks.remove(id);
    if (track != null) {
        track.setId(-1);
        freeIds.add(id);
    } else {
        Terminal.printError("track with ID " + track.getId() + " doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```