# sort arraylist with key ascending

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

```
map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(); 
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

map.put("id", id);
map.put("amt", amt);

list.add(map);
```

How to  sort the list with ascending order of `amt`. I was unable to do this.
I'd really appreciate any help.

I am adding `id`, `amt` in loop. How to sort with key as `amt`?

```
id=1,2,3,4,5
amt=1000,33333,77,9087,5432
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you exactly want. I can't make head or tail from your problem statement

Comment: Should be same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Hello Prateek.Its a for loop with values --> id and amount as shown above and its added into arraylist -->list .I would like to sort the array in ascending order of amount and get the respective id for the same.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simply use** `TreeMap`:

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

map.put("id", "id");
map.put("amd", "amd");

list.add(map);

System.out.println(list);
```

**Output:**

```
[{amd=amd, id=id}]
```

Now if the `Id` is in upper case and `amd` in lower case then you should to override the default behavior of `TreeMap` using `Comparator` in the constructor (to ensure that the sorting for strings keys is correct):

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase());
        }
    });
```

[Look to the `TreeMap` API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: Where are you specifying the sort to be done w.r.t to amt and not id ?

Comment: also I have 
          map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(); and list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: @jason Strings are sorted lexicographically, since a comes before i the amt comes before id.

Comment: How can I make it specific ? if it was not amt but some other alphabet .Trying to be robust in implementation.

Comment: Thanks  Magicano that was great explanation.What if I have 4 more variables along with the above id,amt but it still has compare amt.Will the above example still work ?

Comment: Its working for now will get back to you if I have more queries .Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have method to retrieve values from arraylist  :: retrieveValuesFromList(list); but I am getting original list not the sorted list the method contains:  
 public static void retrieveValuesFromList(List list)
     {
            int size = list.size();
         for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
         {
          
          Map<String, String> o = (Map<String, String>) list.get(i);  

          String amt;
    amt=o.get("amt");
    Log.e(" amt", amt);
    

          String id;
    id=o.get("id");
    Log.e("id", id);
         

         
         
     }

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear as at some point you seem to mention sorting a list with only one element (your map). But I assume you want to sort the keys in that map (either inside the map or after adding them all to some list).

However, for sorting lists you have `Collections.sort()` which can rely on both natural order (if elements implement `Comparable`) or a custom `Comparator`. Also, you can have a look at `SortedSet` (and the `TreeSet` implementation) if you want to have the order maintained while you add/remove elements.

For maintaining a map with ordered keys, you have the `SortMap` (with a notable implementation: `TreeMap`) which will make sure the order it preserved at any moment -- you can add the elements randomly and whenever you iterate you'll get the keys in order. Again the order will can be the natural one (provided by `Comparable.compareTo`) or you can provide custom ordering by implementing the `Comparator` interface.