# how to sort a Fraction part of Float Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I jave a map containing String as Key and float as value in java.
How to sort them efficiently.
I tried to use comparator , but stuck badly.

```
Map<String,Float> map = new HashMap<String,Float>();
map.put("A",(float)3.24);
map.put("A",(float)3.14);
```

**Sorry my problem is to sort based on fractional part of the value ie .24 and .14**

How to sort the above in java.

Comment: How do you want them sorted? And in what way did you get *"stuck"* when using a custom comparator?

Comment: let me know where did you stuck?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Answer (score 2):

If you want them ordered by key, use a Treemap instead of a Hashmap.

[Javadoc for Treemap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`. `TreeMap`  will automatically sorted.

Note: HashMap, TreeMap wont allow duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeMap that implement SortedMap.
check this link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/sorted-map.html