# Reorder a HashMap by its greater key

Tags: java

Supposing that I have a hashmap with the following structure:

```
HashMap<int, String> players = new HashMap<int, String>();
players.put(2, 'player1');
players.put(1, 'player2');
players.put(4, 'player3');
players.put(3, 'player4');
players.put(5, 'player5');
```

How can I output it like this with a for loop?

```
5, player5
4, player3
3, player4
2, player1
1, player2
```

Comment: use a Treemap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a  [`TreeMap<k,v>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)
 with the existing HashMap

```
   Map<int, String> newMap = new TreeMap(Collections.reverseOrder());
    newMap.putAll(players);
```

So that your existing `players` map is unchanged. And you get the `newMap` sorted in descending order