# Sort list of countries

Tags: java

I want to generate a list of all countries in a sorted list. I tried this:

```
public Map<String, String> getCountryNameCodeList() {

        String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();

        Arrays.sort(countryCodes);

        Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<>();

        for (String countryCode : countryCodes) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

            list.put(obj.getDisplayCountry(), obj.getCountry());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

But for some reason the list is unsorted. What is the proper way to fort it?

Comment: Use TreeMap<>() instead of HashMap<>().

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't preserve/guarantee any order. Use `TreeMap` it automatically sorts entries based on keys

Comment: You can also use LinkedHashMap because it holds the order.

Comment: Side note: don't call your method `getCountryNameCodeList` as this implies that you're returning a list, not a map.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java

Comment: Don't call something which is a `Map` `list`. That's just confusing. (And don't call a `Locale` `obj`). Give things meaningful names.

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` is unsorted, use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a
>   doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked
>   list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in
>   which keys were inserted into the map (**insertion-order**).

Just change

```
Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<>();
```

to:

```
Map<String, String> list = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Comment: Does he need to call sort() on it or something too before returning it?