# How can I sort a Map<LocalDate, Integer>?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, hashmap, chronological

I just want to know **how I can sort by chnrological order a Map<LocalDate, Integer>**.

Here's the first line of my code :

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer> commitsPerDate = new HashMap<>();
```

Afterwards, I fill in my Map with any value (but not in chronological order).
And when I display the values of my Map, it is displayed in this order :

```
for(var item : commitsPerDate.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println(item.getKey() + " = " + item.getValue());
}
```

```
2020-08-31 = 1
2020-09-30 = 3
2020-09-29 = 1
2020-09-28 = 5
2020-09-27 = 5
2020-08-27 = 4
2020-09-25 = 3
2020-10-21 = 1
2020-10-18 = 1
2020-10-17 = 5
2020-10-16 = 4
2020-10-15 = 5
2020-10-14 = 6
2020-09-14 = 1
2020-10-13 = 2
2020-09-13 = 2
```

And I would like it to be sorted in chronological order so that the display is in the same order.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want map to order elements by *key* then you can use TreeMap instead of HashMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Pshemo has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522681/how-can-i-sort-a-maplocaldate-integer#comment114089625_64522681), if you want the map to order elements by key then you can use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<LocalDate, Integer> commitsPerDate = new TreeMap<>();
        commitsPerDate.put(LocalDate.parse("2020-08-31"), 1);
        commitsPerDate.put(LocalDate.parse("2020-09-30"), 3);
        commitsPerDate.put(LocalDate.parse("2020-09-29"), 1);
        commitsPerDate.put(LocalDate.parse("2020-09-28"), 5);

        System.out.println(commitsPerDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{2020-08-31=1, 2020-09-28=5, 2020-09-29=1, 2020-09-30=3}
```

**In the reverse order:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<LocalDate, Integer> commitsPerDate = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        commitsPerDate.put(LocalDate.parse("2020-08-31"), 1);
        commitsPerDate.put(LocalDate.parse("2020-09-30"), 3);
        commitsPerDate.put(LocalDate.parse("2020-09-29"), 1);
        commitsPerDate.put(LocalDate.parse("2020-09-28"), 5);

        System.out.println(commitsPerDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{2020-09-30=3, 2020-09-29=1, 2020-09-28=5, 2020-08-31=1}
```

For any reason, if you have to use `HashMap`, check [How to sort Map values by key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java)