# Java - How to specify the order that Firestore retrieves field names?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve all field names from a document (the document name is the userID) under a collection called "taskboards". I want Firestore to retrieve these field names in a specific order but I don't know how.

Here is the following code:

```
userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DocumentReference userTaskboardRef = fStore.collection("taskboards").document(userID)

userTaskboardRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){

            List<String> columnsList = new ArrayList<>();

            Map<String, Object> map = task.getResult().getData();
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
                columnsList.add(entry.getKey());
                Log.d("TAG", entry.getKey());
                Log.d("TAG", entry.getValue().toString());

            }
```

For example:

I would like Firestore to retrieve the following field names in the order "To Do, Doing, Done". Here is a picture of how the field names are stored in my Firestore.

[image]

The above code works and retrieves the field names but it retrieves them in the order "Doing, To Do, Done". Here is a picture of TAG showing the order.

[image]

I'm quite new to Android Studio so can anybody help me out? Is it even possible to specify the order in which the field names are retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

The order of fields in a document is undefined, as is the order of entries in a `Map`.

The screenshot of the Firebase console in your questions shows the fields in alphabetical order. If you want to replicate that in your code, you can sort the keys with a `TreeMap`:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<>(task.getResult().getData());
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
    ...
```

Also see:

- [How to sort Map values by key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java)