# Sort the map value based on precedence in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "PRECEDENCE": "3",
                        "ENTITY_CLASS": "ACCOUNT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "PRECEDENCE": "16",
                        "ENTITY_CLASS": "PRODUCT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "PRECEDENCE": "1",
                        "ENTITY_CLASS": "ACCOUNT"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the output should be ordered based value in ascending order

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "PRECEDENCE": "1",
                        "ENTITY_CLASS": "ACCOUNT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "PRECEDENCE": "3",
                        "ENTITY_CLASS": "PRODUCT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "PRECEDENCE": "16",
                        "ENTITY_CLASS": "ACCOUNT"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Current structure I have

```
Response 
        Set<essage> message
                        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
```

I was trying by manual compare. is there a way I can iterate and sort the map values.

How can I optimize efficiently?

Comment: there is an example here might be useful.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-hashmap-according-key-value-java/

Comment: Also, If you want to sort by interger value of the keys, there is a comparator example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to change the message type from a `Set` to `List` if the order is important for you.

Next, you have to implement `Comparator` for your `Message` to simplify the way of sorting, the `compare` method may look like next:

```java
    public int compareTo(Message msg1, Message msg2){
       return msg1.parameters.get("PRECEDENCE")
                  .compareTo(msg2.parameters.get("PRECEDENCE")) 
    }
```

Don't forget to add different null checks.

Then you can simply call `response.messages.sort(new YourMessageComparator())` to get sorted messages by precedence.