# Gettings Hashmap keys in ascending order

Tags: java

I have a Hashmap like below, Getting below data from database

```
Map<String, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
hashmap.put("18-64 Years", 31334);
hashmap.put("6-17 Years", 3788);
hashmap.put("65 and Above Years", 24929);
```

I want to get list of keys in ascending order from above Hashmap.

Can someone please, help on how get them in correct order?

I have tried order by in SQL query, but that didn't worked in the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort Map values by key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-can-i-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
List<String> sortedList = hashMap.keySet().stream().sorted(
  (k1, k2) -> {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern.match(k1);
    matcher1.find();
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(matcher1.group());
    
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern.match(k2);
    matcher2.find();
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(matcher2.group());
    
    return num1 - num2;
  }
).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be loading the data from a database and put it into the map and since I assume you not only want the keys ordered but actually the values as well you might try a different approach, e.g.

1. use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap` since that maintains entries ordered by key
2. do the ordering in the query and use a `LinkedHashMap` since that maintains data in insertion order

The problem with your keys, however, is that they are strings but seem to actually represent ranges. Thus `"6-17 years"` will be considered larger than `"18-64 years"`. To sort those correctly you'd need to parse the strings into numbers for lower and upper bound and sort by those.

Ideally, instead of using strings as the keys you'd use a proper object that represents that range, e.g. one like this (simplified to keep it readable):

```
class YearRange implements Comparable<YearRange> {
  int lowerBound;
  int upperBound;

  public int compareTo(YearRange other) {
    int r = Integer.compare(lowerBound, other.lowerBound);
    if (r == 0) {
      r = Integer.compare(upperBound, other.upperBound);
    }
    
    return r
  }
}
```

Then use a `Map<YearRange, Integer>`, e.g. as a `TreeMap<YearRange, Integer>`.

If you really need to use the string keys, then you'd need to provide a `Comparator<String>` that parses the numbers from the strings and compares them, but that can hit performance quite a bit for larger maps since each comparison would require to parse the same strings again and again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>(hashmap.keySet());

    Collections.sort(keysList);  // or keysList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());

    System.out.println("keysList = " + keysList);
```